# Ignoring UIGestureRecognizer when hitting button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a gesture recognizer set up so that my toolbar slides down when the screen is tapped.  When I hit a button on the bar, that counts as a tap.  How do I cancel the gesture in those cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can look at the SimpleGestureRecognizers sample project.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the button.
    if ((touch.view == button) && (gestureRecognizer == tapRecognizer)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The gestureRecognizer.view is being listed as the overall view, not the toolbar/buttons.

Comment: This if statement works for ignoring every button in a toolbar.  Took me a minute to find it, thought it might be worth adding. if([touch.view isDescendantOfView:_toolbar])

Comment: My solution was `return !([touch.view isKindOfClass[UIButton class]])` to allow events for all buttons on my view.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view is UIButton {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```