# How prevent a parent UIView to receive touch from UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, keyboard

I have an UIView (from UIViewController) that receive touch and remove keyboard. In the same screen I've a UIButton that show the password, when I touch in UIButton the touch goes to UIView and remove keyboard.

How prevent the UIView to receive touch from UIButton?

I'd try `.isExclusiveTouch` but didn't work.

## EDIT

My extension that remove the keyboard:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard)
        )
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

In my ViewController, the button:

```
self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myButtonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(self.myButton)
```

Comment: Do you have some code you can show us? It would help us. Thanks!

Comment: yes! add in the question now...

Comment: @user2921672 I think that your problem is that your UITextField is loosing the focus, I mean it's removed from first responder, and that is why the keyboard is dismissed, but this is don't related to UIButton passing touch to superView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use gestures just use this code

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Here when you touch any part of view (not buttons) keyboard will be dismissed by code (view.endEditing(true))

Answer (score 0):

Try setting userIntrecationEnabled to false.

```
//example
yourView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

If user interaction is disabled for a view, it will ignore touches.

Comment: You might try disabling UIButton if you do not want it being tappable

Comment: I want the UIButton working, but do not propagate the tap to the UIView.

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942133/ignoring-uigesturerecognizer-when-hitting-button?rq=1